# How to detect if SendMessage() API is called

Tags: winapi, detection, sendmessage

I have the first program (written in Win32 API) using a lot of `SendMessage()` API; it's already done and works.
The problem is I want to write a second one that can detect `SendMessage()` is called in the first program and if possible, capture its data (`HANDLE, WPARAM, LPARAM...`)

Does anyone know solution for this problem?

The `DLLStudy.dll`:

EDIT: ok, this is what I have so far.

```
#include <windows.h>

#define SIZE 6

typedef int (WINAPI *pMessageBoxW)(HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT);
int WINAPI MyMessageBoxW(HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT);

void BeginRedirect(LPVOID);

pMessageBoxW pOrigMBAddress = NULL;
BYTE oldBytes[SIZE] = {0};
BYTE JMP[SIZE] = {0};
DWORD oldProtect, myProtect = PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE;

INT APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hDLL, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved)
{
    switch(Reason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Test", "OK", MB_OK);
        pOrigMBAddress = (pMessageBoxW)
            GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"user32.dll"), "MessageBoxW");
        if(pOrigMBAddress != NULL)
            BeginRedirect(MyMessageBoxW);    
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        memcpy(pOrigMBAddress, oldBytes, SIZE);
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void BeginRedirect(LPVOID newFunction)
{
    BYTE tempJMP[SIZE] = {0xE9, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0xC3};
    memcpy(JMP, tempJMP, SIZE);
    DWORD JMPSize = ((DWORD)newFunction - (DWORD)pOrigMBAddress - 5);
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pOrigMBAddress, SIZE, 
                    PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
    memcpy(oldBytes, pOrigMBAddress, SIZE);
    memcpy(&JMP[1], &JMPSize, 4);
    memcpy(pOrigMBAddress, JMP, SIZE);
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pOrigMBAddress, SIZE, oldProtect, NULL);
}

int  WINAPI MyMessageBoxW(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR lpText, LPCWSTR lpCaption, UINT uiType)
{
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pOrigMBAddress, SIZE, myProtect, NULL);
    memcpy(pOrigMBAddress, oldBytes, SIZE);
    int retValue = MessageBoxW(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uiType);
    memcpy(pOrigMBAddress, JMP, SIZE);
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pOrigMBAddress, SIZE, oldProtect, NULL);
    return retValue;
}
```

The `Injector.cpp`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char const Path[]="DLLStudy.dll";

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    HANDLE hWnd, hProcess, AllocAdresse, hRemoteThread;
    DWORD PID;

    hWnd = FindWindow(0,"Notepad");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId((HWND)hWnd, &PID);

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, PID);

    AllocAdresse = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, sizeof(Path), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (void*)AllocAdresse, (void*)Path, sizeof(Path), 0);
    hRemoteThread=CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"),"LoadLibraryA"), AllocAdresse, 0, 0);

    WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE);

    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, AllocAdresse, sizeof(Path), MEM_DECOMMIT);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
```

EDIT 2: Well, I've managed to make it work. So how to get data from `SendMessage()` if it is called?

Comment: Can you modify first app? If yes, just create a global event and trigger it in first app, in second app open event and WaitForXXXObject.

Comment: Assuming first app is protected, no source code!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CreateRemoteThread to inject a DLL into the first application. In the DLL's entrymain, you'd write code to remap the external call to SendMessage to your own SendMessageX which can then tell your other application when SendMessage is being called, and then pass the original call to the WIN32 subsystem.

Comment: could you please provide a sample? I don't have much idea on this.

Comment: @xjaphx do a websearch with the keywords that this answer provides.

Comment: got it worked! so how can I remap external call to `SendMessage()` ?